# Casting multiple-inherited object to and from void*

Tags: c++, casting, multiple-inheritance

I know, that similar questions have been already answered, but something still puzzles me. The examples here are naturally simplified and stripped-from-irrelevant-stuff excerpts from a real code base.

```
class X {...};
class Y {...};
class Z : public X, public Y {...}
```

Now I create the Z object and put it through C interface (as `void*`)

```
Z* z = new Z();
doSomeWeirdStuff(z);
```

And in some callback I get my object back (still as `void*`).

```
void callback(void* data)
{
    Z* z1 = static_cast<Z*>(data);
    Z* z2 = dynamic_cast<Z*>(static_cast<Y*>(data));
}
```

`z1` is rubbish. Since `X` and `Y` have the same layout, when I debug, I see `z1` having Y's values in X's part of the object. I expected, that, since I created the object as Z, that should be correct. Instead `z2` seems to be correct.

By the way - classes have no common ancestors and this is not a virtual inheritance.

Why? What am I missing here?

---

Edit:
What I have been missing is pretty simple and I should bang my head against the wall for that. Long story short: `X` and `Y` used `this` to initialize the user data in their constructors, so I was really passing a pointer to `Y` when I thought it has been `Z`...

I'm going to accept @user2079303's answer because it has made me check the code another three times to spot this...

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That first cast is correct, it should work.

Comment: You might want to edit out the obscenity before someone complains.

Comment: `static_cast` to and from `void *` is guaranteed to be safe for class pointers (i think this is specified somewhere in a standard). You might have encountered a memory corruption.

Comment: What do you mean by "*bullshit*"? False, incorrect, garbage? I don't mind cussing as long as it doesn't introduce ambiguity. It would be more meaningful to show exactly what are you observing. Maybe the compiler is given freedom in choice of order in which it orders parent members, and did `Y`,`X` as memory layout of `Z`.

Comment: In the code you have posted: `z1` is correct, and `z2` is undefined behaviour. The explanation of the discrepancy between this and your observations can only be resolved by posting a complete program that gives the problem. There are too many possibilities to list about how code you haven't shown us could be affecting this.

Comment: I will try to narrow what I have to MCVE if this is possible. Right now I can only say, that I'm writing a node.js module and the class in question goes as user data to libuv queue. Then it has to be casted back to the right pointer in the callback. I'll see if I can recreate this behaviour without all that node/libuv stuff.

Comment: @Jakub: Did you check the address of pointer passed to the C interface and compare it to the one passed to `callback`? Is the interface asynchronous? If yes, is it possible that you've accidentally deleted `z` by the time callback is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion for `z1` is correct and guaranteed to work by the standard. Here's a quote from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) about `static_cast`.

> A prvalue of type pointer to void (possibly cv-qualified) can be converted to pointer to any type. Conversion of any pointer to pointer[sic] to void and back to pointer to the original (or more cv-qualified) type preserves its original value.

[This](http://ideone.com/VPUoAm) example runs without a hitch.

```
#include <cassert>

struct X {
    int a;
};
struct Y {
    int b;
};
struct Z : public X, public Y {
    int c;
};

void callback(void* data) {
    Z* z1 = static_cast<Z*>(data);
    assert(z1->a == 1);
    assert(z1->b == 2);
    assert(z1->c == 3);
}

int main() {
    Z z;
    z.a = 1;
    z.b = 2;
    z.c = 3;
    callback((void*) &z);
}
```

> Why? What am I missing here?

Possibly undefined behaviour that has overwritten your memory.

Comment: The debugger only confirms that something is wrong. What I got is a  crash with "invalid access" error because it reaches some random values.

Comment: @Jakub: Ok, in that case, I'll remove the doubt about debugger sanity in my answer. You should probably mention the crash in your question.

Comment: You have made me doubt in my code again, which is a good thing. I've found the problem (see edit). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about a "C interface", are you compiling a library and an interface seperately? If so, make sure both are using the same compiler settings, i.e. debug/release mode, safe iterators on/off, etc.

Because object layout can differ depending on compiler flags.

Comment: If he is only inspecting the object in the same file as he creates it, this would not to be an issue. The `void *` can pass through other code that knows nothing about the object. But we can't say for sure just based on what is posted so far, of course.

Comment: Yes, the C part merely transfers the pointer back to my callback, which is even in the same translation unit (*.cpp file)